# Backup software for macOS which support SMB

Tags: networking, backup, macos

I'm using Bvckup 2 on Windows which can do daily specific folder/files backup to a home NAS (through an SMB share) and allows me to specify the network username/password in case it can't login to the SMB share.

Looking for something equivalent for macOS. I need to be able to specify the directories and setup an SMB share withing the app, otherwise I'll need to be constantly setting up the SMB connection. Any kind of encryption is a plus.

SmartBackup, for example, can't handle SMB correctly. Whenever I open the laptop lid I get a message that it can't connect to or find the share.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you check out Cloudberry Backup for Mac. It supports multiple cloud storage providers and local backup destinations. Check out the link below

https://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/cloudberry-backup-for-mac-os-supports-local-backup-and-retention-policy/